# Cannot get latest value of useState in Redux subscribe

Tags: redux

When the state in Redux is updated, if it is different from the useState of the current page, the useState in the page will be updated, but the value in the red box will not change after the update, it is always the default true.

```js
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import store from "./redux";
    import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { setState } from "./redux/modules/menu";
    
    function App() {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const [baseState, setBaseState] = useState(true);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("baseState :>> ", baseState);
      }, [baseState]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const unSubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
          console.log(store.getState().menu.state, baseState);
    
          if (store.getState().menu.state !== baseState) {
            setBaseState(store.getState().menu.state);
          }
        });
    
        return () => unSubscribe();
      }, []);
    
      const buttonEvent = () => {
        const storeState = store.getState().menu.state;
        dispatch(setState(!storeState));
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>value: {baseState + ""}</h1>
          <button onClick={buttonEvent}>change</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

[image]

run result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So if i got your question, what you are doing is, on a button click, you are changing the redux state and on that basis, you want to change the local state.

But in your `useEffect()` (2nd one);

```
useEffect(() => {
        const unSubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
          console.log(store.getState().menu.state, baseState);
    
          if (store.getState().menu.state !== baseState) {
            setBaseState(store.getState().menu.state);
          }
        });
    
        return () => unSubscribe();
      }, []);
```

You are giving an empty array as 2nd argument, which means this useEffect is going to get triggered only on the first render(similar to componentDidMount in class components), thus will never know if the redux state has changed.

Thus, to make it working, just remove them (like we have componentDidUpdate in class components).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the method you mentioned can solve this problem, but every time you click the change button, it will clear the subscription and create it again

Comment: yes you are right, but you need to do something which triggers the change which you wanit